How to use Fancybox 5 to show a photo when clicking a Leaflet marker - and group them with all other photos
I have this piece of code to open a photo when marker is clicked on Leaflet-map. And it works fine.
function onMouseFancybox(feature, layer)
{
    foto="images/" + feature.properties['uuid'] + ".jpg";
    tijd=feature.properties['timestamp'].replace('T', ' ');
    uuid=feature.properties['uuid'];
    caption=tijd + "<br>";
    Fancybox.show([{ src: foto, caption: caption} ]);
    layer.setStyle({fillColor: "#ff0000", color: "#ff0000"});
    console.log(uuid);
}

geojsonFeatureCamera=<?php echo json_encode($geojsonc)?>;
var geojsonc = L.geoJSON(geojsonFeatureCamera, {
    pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) 
    return L.circleMarker(latlng, geojsonMarkerOptionsCamera);
    },
    onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
        console.log(feature);
        layer.on('click', function(e) {
            onMouseFancybox(feature, layer);
        });
    }
});


But I wish to group all photos (uuid's in each feature) to be able to go to the next or previous.
I know there is a grouping-mechanism and Fancybox.bind but I do not understand how to use that in this situation, if possible.

Just add more gallery items when you start Fancybox, something like this:
Fancybox.show(
  // Gallery items
  [
    // First image
    { src: foto, caption: caption},
    // Second 
    { src: foto2, caption: caption2}
    // etc
  ],
  {
    // Gallery options
  }
);

